# Getting 5 results per item - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have a list of causes and a list of matches (an object that holds two foreign keys), and for each causes that fits some condition, I want to get the first five matches to that cause. However I'm having trouble doing it.

I started with this code, selecting all matches for the selected causes

```
SELECT * FROM matches m
WHERE m.cause_id in (
    SELECT cz.id
        FROM causes cz
        WHERE (*condition*)
```

Then tried joins so I could limit it, but I haven't been able to find how to.

```
SELECT * FROM matches m
WHERE (*condition*)
JOIN causes cz ON m.cause_id = cz.id

????
```

'Limit' limits the total number of end results, and I can't limit the number of causes matched either. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you have a list of causes that result from the condition you apply, and you want to get the first 5 matches for each of those conditions?

If that's correct, you could use Window Functions to pull this off:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            m.*,
            c.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY m.id) as rowcount
        FROM
            matches m JOIN causes c ON m.cause_id = c.id
    ) sub
WHERE sub.rowcount <=5
```

The key is in that `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY m.id) as rowcount` which says "Make a sequential row number starting at 1 for each distinct cause id. Order the numbering by the match id". Then we just filter those results for row numbers less than or equal to 5.

Comment: Something with this isn't working correctly; the query still returns all the results. 
You might be misunderstanding, I want the first five matches for each cause that matches the conditions. Slightly different than the what you said.

Comment: I figured it out, you're partitioning on the wrong id. It should be `PARTITION BY c.id`

Comment: Oh shoot! Sorry about that. I did it correctly in the paragraph below, but screwed it up in the actual query :(  Awesome! for figuring it out!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what "first five" matches means.  It is tempting to write your query using `LIMIT`, but I'm not sure that is what you mean:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM matches m
WHERE m.cause_id in (SELECT cz.id
                     FROM causes cz
                     WHERE (*condition*)
                     ORDER BY cz.id
                     LIMIT 5
                    );
```

Instead, use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT cm.*
FROM (SELECT m.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.cause_id ORDER BY cz.id) as seqnum
      FROM matches m JOIN
           causes cz
           ON m.cause_id = cz.id
      WHERE (*condition*)
     ) cm
WHERE seqnum <= 5;
```

For each cause, this returns five matches.